# byte[] в bytea. PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql, npgsql

возникла следующая проблем. Есть байт массив, который храниться в PostgreSQL в ячейке формата bytea. Байт массив получается парсингом DataRow:

```
private byte[] ParseRow(DataRow row)
{
return bytes = (byte[])row["Node"],
}
```

При получение из БД все хорошо, с байт массивом можно работать, изменять, но при составление запроса

```
var sqlCommand = $"UPDATE {TableName} SET " +
                 $"\"CodeTable\"='{bytes}' " +
                 $"WHERE \"ID\"='{item.Id}'"
```

Но в итоге получается в запросе получается

```
UPDATE "TableName" SET "Node"='System.Byte[]' WHERE "ID"='0024791d-b830-4594-bfad-9c34f6c81292'
```

Данные заносятся без ошибок (но не те).
Перепробовал через Encoding.Default.GetString() преобразовывать, но в таком случае возникает ошибка.
Используется Npgsql, .net7, postgreSQL 8.4

Comment: Upd: вопрос был решен через параметризацию (NpgsqlParameter parameter)

Comment: Если для `byte[]` массива вызвать `.ToString()` или использовать его в интерполяции строки, то получите строчку `System.Byte[]`, так что всё верно. Как написали, так и работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вопрос был решен через параметризацию. Примерный код:

```cs
var comm = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlCommand, Connection.conn);
NpgsqlParameter parameter = new NpgsqlParameter("@Node", NpgsqlDbType.Bytea);
parameter.Value = bytes;
comm.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Вообще задание таким образом параметров запроса - примерно единственный верный и надежный путь составления запроса в ADO.NET